# how do i define the height of rectangle?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

"Create a rectangle with coordinates x1=15, y1=20, width=120, height=150"
Does it have to do something with the coordinates? Cause there's no 'height' option

````
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

canv = Canvas(window, width=200, height=250, bg="white")
canv.pack(pady=15)

coords = [15, 20, 0, 0]
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(coords, width=120)
window.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 2):

The coordinates are how you define the height and width of the rectangle. No height definition is required.

This is from : https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-canvas/

Python Tkinter Canvas Rectangle

```
Python Tkinter Canvas has built-in features to create shapes.
To create a rectangle create_rectangle() method is used.
This method accepts 4 parameters x1, y1, x2, y2. Here x1 and y1 are the coordinates for the top left corner and x2 and y2 are the coordinates for the bottom right corner.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your `coords` define the positions of two opposite corners of the rectangle, `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`. You have the coordinates of the top left corner already, so you need to figure out the coordinates of the bottom right corner using the given height and width - you simply add these to the coordinates.

In this example you simply would change your coords from `[15, 20, 0, 0]` to `[15, 20, 135, 170]`.

One thing to note is that the coordinate system in Tkinter is defined with (0,0) at the top left of the window, so a higher y coordinate means further down the window and higher x coordinate means further right.

Comment: also i wanted to ask if a should delete the width option after setting the coordinates

Comment: Yes, the width parameter of the `create_rectangle` function refers to the border width, not the width of the rectangle which is purely determined by the coordinates provided.